# How to programatically send SMS notifications to 1 million users using queues?

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, sms, microservices

**What we have?**

An API build in Node.js (using Moleculer.js for micro-services and PostgreSQL for storing data) which has the functionality of keeping track of users and user groups. We have in average 3k users per group, and a user can be part of multiple groups.

**What we want to achieve?**

We want to create a special service which will send text messages. The admins will select multiple groups, the code will remove the duplicated users and send them an SMS.

After a selection we can have around 1 million users. How can we send them text messages in an efficient way?

**What have we tried?**

1. Paginate the users and for each page send a request to the SMS service.

   ```js
   const users = db.getPage(1); // [{ id: 1, phone: '+123456789' }, ...]
   smsClient.sendBulk(users);
   ```

   **PROBLEM:** The user list in the database can change in the process and can affect the pagination by giving us duplicates or skipping some users.
2. Load all the results in the memory and send all the users to the SMS service.

   ```js
   const users = db.getAll(); // [..., { id: 988123, phone: '+987654321' }]
   smsClient.sendBulk(users);
   ```

   **PROBLEM:** We think it's a bad idea, resource wise, to make this kind of queries to the database and keep them in the memory. In the same time, we don't want to send 1 million entities through an HTTP request to the SMS service.

How can we select a 1 million users and send them an SMS message without worry about duplicates, skipped data or any other alteration to the admin's selection? We were thinking about queues as a necessary step but after we find a solution for the cases mentioned above. Or, is the queue part of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

> How can we select a 1 million users and send them an SMS message without worry about duplicates, skipped data, or any other alteration to the admin's selection?

For managing **duplicates** You could use an additional DB to save a Hash Table for the users that been handled already. This is a bit more expensive because you will need to check the user before each SMS send.

Managing not **skipping** is a bit tricky because you will need to add more recipients to an ongoing SMS transaction. You will need the ability to detect (hook) when a user is added to a group and add it as recipients to the ongoing transactions accordingly.
You will need to find a fast DB and save that user in a `HashSet` for a fast `set` and `get` (`O(1)`)

> We were thinking about queues as a necessary step but after we find a solution for the cases mentioned above. Or, is the queue part of the solution?

Defenently. Queue is the correct way to go for this scenario (queueing many small tasks). Some queues come with a `re-queue` features that will re-queue any task that didn't get acknowledgment.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check out RabbitMQ.message-driven microservices

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating an indirect state between the user and sent SMS? Something like **SmsRequest** / **SmsTask** / however you'd call it.

It'd consist of necessary user-data, message content, status of the request (**to-send**, **sending**, **sent**, **failed**, ...) and some additional metadata depending on your needs.

Then the first step you'd do is to prepare these request and store them in db, effectively making a queue out of a table. You can add some constraints on user and message type that'd prevent any duplicates and then start second asynchronous process that simply fetches requests in **to-send** state, sets the state to **sending** and then saves the outcome.

This also gives you the benefit of audit + you can batch the outgoing messages and.

Of course it'd increase your data volume significantly but I guess it's cheap nowadays anyway.